# web.xml of every application deployed in Tomcat 7.0.52 disappeared

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, servlets, web

I have 5 Applications running within Apache Tomcat 7.0.52 in production environment. All the applications were running well through several months. But yesterday when I restarted the tomcat (because there are some updates on ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/context.xml), all the apps could not be started correctly thus causing 404 error when visiting.

I've gone through the catalina.out file but found no useful messages that indicates the error. Finally I found out the web.xml of each app (located in ${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/web.xml) had disappeared!  Even include the web.xml of tomcat manager(${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml)!

PS. I used to deploy the apps via tomcat manager page, just by picking a war file and then upload.

It really confused me a lot how this strange thing could happen! Could anyone give me any advice for this question? Thank you a lot~

Answer (score 0):

Somebody, (possibly through a security exploit in your software) has executed a command something like the following:

```
 find / -name web.xml -exec rm {} \;
```

Check the shell command history before panicking.

Comment: Thank you, I've checked but there's no such command was executed and no one else could log on the server. I doubt if there's some mistake made by Tomcat

Comment: If your application contains security flaws then [Injection Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2017-A1-Injection) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps
[web-xml-frequently-being-deleted-from-tomcat-manager-servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778670/web-xml-frequently-being-deleted-from-tomcat-manager-servlet)

In addition to *@Steve C*'s suggestion, I would also recommend the suggestion mentioned in the link

> setting the privileges of the files to read-only

so that it does not occur in the future.

---

I would have added this as a comment, but I lack the reputation to do so.

Comment: My Tomcat is located in our own server rather than Aliyun VPS. And I've checked the permission of the web.xml is rw-------, does it matters?

Comment: Actually as mentioned here [why-can-rm-remove-read-only-files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/why-can-rm-remove-read-only-files) , if there is  write+execute permission on the parent directory, then the files under it can be deleted.
You can try making the WEB-INF directory read-only.